# Which all iOS version shall be supported for a new iPad app in development?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

this might be a subjective question with no correct answer but I am seeking the inputs from the community here as this is our first application and the inputs are important for our development team.

Considering the iOS version stats from couple of apps(http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/), 75% of usrebase has already migrated to the iOS 6. With the number of platform changes that have happened in iOS6, I  am looking for inputs if a new iPad app(with target audience as designers and creative professionals) shall consider dropping the ios5 altogether or if these data cannot be taken as a general update trend?

Please suggest.

Comment: Depends entirely on what you want. Is it important to you to support users still on iOS 5? How long will it be before your product is ready for distribution, and how many iOS 5 users will there be then? Does you customer have a requirement for iOS 5? Do you need/want to use features specific to iOS 6?

Comment: As mentioned, we aim to target creative designers/professional(who might already be on iOS6) and the app is currently under development which might take another three months to be live on app store. *how many ios5 users would be there then? -> this is the reply i was seeking from the community.

Comment: more specifically, the question is around if the data published at http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/ can be taken as generic trend or if it is one of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that all of my devices are not tracked by the page you provided the link to.
I think that statistics could be reliable for you if the apps used to collect them were directed at the same market segment as your app, which I understand is not the case.

That said, the major impairment I see in only supporting iOS 6 for an iPad app is that you are excluding all iPad 1 devices, which are not supported anymore. There are still a bunch of them around, so I would do the effort to support at least iOS 5, possibly by even cutting some "advanced" feature requiring iOS 6 on that device (iOS 5) only.

Just my 2 cents.

My philosophy is to try and support the most of iOS versions until I do really need a feature in my app that is available only on a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple in my mind.  If you want to use ios 6 functionality (such as collection views) target ios 6.  If you are not using any ios 6 specific functionality, you might as well target 5.0 or even earlier to widen your audience.  Generally speaking, iOS users upgrade to new os versions very rapidly.  That said, even if you use ios 6 functionality, you could check the device and use earlier API for earlier OS versions.